# What are some methods to get rid of and prevent pink mold in the bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, tile, mold

I have some pink mold on the seam where the bathtub connects to my wall tiles. There's also some on the grout on some of my tiles.

I've tried to clean them with ajax. It doesn't get it all off. I've also tried to spray the tub and the tiles with a 50/50 solution of vinegar/water and that didn't fully get rid of them.

How do I get rid of the pink mold? Once I get rid of it, how do I keep it off?

Comment: I think what you are seeing could be fluoride that is put in the water by the utility company.  Try CLR or Clorox clean-up

Answer (score 8):

The pink stuff is a bacterial biofilm. Cleaning agents containing bleach work well to kill the stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are seeing could be fluoride that is put in the water by the utility company. Try CLR or Clorox clean-up –

Comment: I don't think so ... I am on a well, therefore have no flouride, and have a small patch of pink mold on the floor of my bathroom.

Answer (score 0):

Hydrogen peroxide poured directly on the pink grime can be effective at removing it, especially if coupled with light scrubbing with an old toothbrush or sponge), should you wish to use a bleach alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Using Oxiclean powder, I made a thick paste, applied it with an old toothbrush, and let it sit overnight. Then used an old electric toothbrush to remove the paste. Worked well.

Also tried sprinkling a heavy layer of baking soda then spraying with vinegar so it bubbled. Left it on for several hours then removed with a toothbrush. Worked well enough to be a feasible alternative to the Oxiclean method.

Several points to keep in mind when reading this answer:

- Used it for grout; no vinyl or silicone edges involved.
- Both methods made the floor slick; had to rinse and wipe several times to "unslick" it.
- No reason to think the pink stuff was mold. When touched, it felt slimy. My guess is that it's a combination of soaps, shampoos, and as mentioned in another reply, flouride.
- This is a cleaning solution. The holy grail would be the clean-and-prevent solution sought in the original question.

Answer (score -2):

Dont breath in that stuff. Look it up guys, it's bad for your health. Once you have it in you home forget it, it's there forever. only answer is to get it grinded off. Toss all your old cloths, sponges etc you use and get microfiber cloths. rags hold the mold you can bleach the hell out of it and it will come back again, again.

Comment: -1 because "grinded off" will typically destroy the underlying surface. At which point you're suggesting the OP replace the floor, tub, sink, or anywhere else this has appeared.